# Java: Move content from one variable to another

Tags: java, variables, reference, clone

I'm currently working on a chess game using Java, and I came accross a problem. Every field of the chessboard might have a chess piece on it, which you can get by typing:

```
field.getPiece() //null or Piece-object
```

Now, when moving a Piece, I wanted to do it like this:

```
field2.setPiece( field1.getPiece() );
field1.setPiece( null );
```

The problem is, that field1 keeps the reference of the piece, and overwrites it with null, so that the Piece gets deleted. So my question is: How do I move the content / reference of a variable to another one, without pointing both variables at the same reference?

Btw: I know, that I could clone my Piece, and then delete the old one, but I hope there is a more efficient way of doing this.

EDIT:
Relevant code:

```
public class Field {
    private Piece piece;

    public Piece getPiece(){ return piece; }

    public void setPiece(Piece piece){
        this.piece = piece;
        piece.setField(this);                //Tell the piece on what field it is (to get position etc.) [LINE 53]
    }
}

public abstract class Piece {
    protected Field field;
    public void setField(Field field){
        this.field = field;
    }
}  

field2.setPiece(field1.getPiece());
field1.setPiece(null);
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void [...].Piece.setField(Field)' on a null object reference
at [...].Field.setPiece(Field.java:53)
```

When removing the last line in the code (`field1.setPiece(null);`), it works (it doesn't crash)

EDIT2: After receiving the answer, I realized, that my idea up there was fully wrong, and the error was caused by a simple problem...

Comment: I'd show the code for your `fieldX` class. If the object has a reference to a `Piece` instance, setting the reference of the `Piece` variable to value `null` in `field1` should not do anything to the `Piece` object itself, *unless* `field1.setPiece(null)` is invoked **before** `field2.setPiece(field1.getPiece())`.

Comment: @Mena Ok, I'll share the relevant code and the exception...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with `piece.setField(this);` line in setPiece method. as when you set a piece null how you can call setField on null object.

so just place a null check before `piece.setField(this);.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) in Field#setPiece method because you try to invoke `piece.setField(this)` when piece is `null`. So rewrite code like this

```
public void setPiece(Piece piece){
    this.piece = piece;
    if (piece != null) {
        piece.setField(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: The other one was faster I guess :D, Thank you anyway